# If a user clicks an action link from w/in a modal and is then taken to a separate page, do they return to that open modal after completing the action?

Tags: modal-windows, workflow, content, modal

I'm designing an internal tool that enables my coworkers to curate post-op care plans for orthopedic patients on our platform (basically sending educational content to users at specific intervals).

I'm running into a challenge with one of the main flows, which is adding exercise videos to a care plans. Right now, on the main care plan page, you click an "Add Exercise" CTA that opens up a modal (shown here) where the user is able to multi-select the exercises to be added. Cool.

**BUT** a dictated requirement was that the user should also be able to create a totally new exercise from the same modal (see arrow). This makes sense in terms of supporting the user's workflow, but I'm stuck on the ensuing flow; like, I know that clicking "Create New Exercise" will flip the user over to the "Create New Exercise" page where they can build that content - but after the user creates the new exercise and clicks save, what does the user return to? Do they return to the original page with the still-open modal that now has a little "Exercise Created" confirmation message?

I honestly think this supports the user's goals best, but is it strange/bad ux that the user comes back to the original page and the original modal is still open? Am I missing another, better, interaction entirely?

Thanks everyone, eager to hear what you think!

[image: should this modal stay open when the user returns from a separate page?]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would make sense for the user to create a new exercise from the main page and not within the modal? This way it gets added straight to the plan.

It feels like the modal is serving search functionality, not creation. Ultimately I don't know your users so I could be wrong but they feel like two different journeys to me. One that is search and add, then one that is create and add?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need modal here. Separate page and back arrow icon will serve well. Your users could search and add exercises and have more space for the list (less scrolling). The stepper could be organized in a more convenient manner, than two steps window.

Here (with modal) you will get problems if the user will select more than 3 exercises. How you will show long-named tags if the user has selected 15 exercises?

Anyway, using page will solve your question).